# Displaying images in RecyclerView using Picasso (or Glide) and retrofit, for authenticated users only

Tags: android, laravel, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-glide

I have been using recyclerview to display my contacts and show their basic data including user images. It works as it should, Picasso is great and I get a very cool looking list.

Right now I am trying to disable users to view images until validated - ie I want to disable viewing images to anyone who is not an authenticated user. 
I have done this on my services and disabled anyone except my laravel app to open the image link. Now I face one issue - when I return image it is not a link, but it is in a `byte[]` format, 
and I cannot display it using Picasso. I could try and convert it to `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);` and then convert bitmap to drawable like: 
`Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);`, and then display drawable as image `imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);` but reading into this I found quite a few drawbacks.

My question would be **what is the best way to display image using picasso or glide, and retrofit to return images for authenticated users only**. Is there a different way I can return image from laravel service?
Is there a way to use the byte format with either picasso or glide? Or is there another format I can convert my `byte[]` to display in the recyclerview, that would not negatively influence performance?

Currently displaying image with Picasso in my ContactsAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ContactsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    holder.userName.setText(contact.getUserName());

    TextDrawable.IBuilder builder = TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .withBorder(0)
            .toUpperCase()
            .endConfig()
            .round();

    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    int color = generator.getColor(contact.getUserId());
    textDrawable = builder.build(contactList.get(position).getUserName().substring(0, 1), color);
    holder.thumbNail.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(AppConfig.URL_PROFILE_PHOTO + contact.getThumbnailUrl()) // DISK URL WITH USER IMAGE NAME
            .placeholder(textDrawable)
            .error(textDrawable)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .into(holder.thumbNail);
}
```

Laravel service converts link to image like this:

```
return Image::make($storagePath)->response();
```

I extracted the ProfileImage method and tried to modify it to use the service I got:

```
private void ProfileImage(HashMap<String, String> user, String name, String id) {
    TokenManager tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createServiceWithAuth(ApiInterface.class, tokenManager);

    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    int color = generator.getColor(id);
    String firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1);
    TextDrawable textDrawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRect(firstLetter, color);
    holder.thumbNail.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getUserImage(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
                try {
                    bytes = response.body().bytes();

                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(/** I CANNOT USE THE URL HERE */)
                            .placeholder(textDrawable)
                            .error(textDrawable)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .fit()
                            .into(holder.thumbNail);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (response.code() == 401) {
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "There was an error: " + response);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you can switch to `Glide`, you can use `Glide.with().load(byte[] model)` directly

Comment: @Bach Vu I can switch :) but would this way negatively influence the app performances? Using that old way with `load(url)` is crazy fast when loading images, and I do not have any issues at all, it's too bad I cannot use it that way anymore.

Comment: I personally have not encountered any performance issue with it, so you can give it a try first to see how it performs in your app.

Comment: @BachVu I will try it tonight and let you know :) Thanks

Comment: @BachVu I have tried this solution, but it is loading images really slow, and with a lot of images the app crashes and I get the `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error

Comment: @BachVu Your answer got me on the right track, so if you answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Just did, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can switch to `Glide`, you can use `Glide.with().load(byte[] model)` directly

```
bytes = response.body().bytes();

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load(bytes)
     .placeholder(textDrawable)
     .error(textDrawable)
     .centerCrop()
     .fitCenter()
     .into(holder.thumbNail);
```